# Cassandra sort by key (TimeUUID)

Tags: cassandra, pycassa, timeuuid

I'm having trouble sorting by key when calling `get_range()` on a column family.

- The keys are TimeUUID
- the key validation class is org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType
- the partitioner is "ByteOrderedPartitioner"

When I call get_range() the results are not returned in the correct order, though.  Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you configured the partitioner (and restart the server) before create the keyspace?

Answer (score 3):

ByteOrderedPartitioner orders by bytes, as the name suggests.  Since the "time" component of a version 1 uuid is not the first bytes, this is NOT the same as TimeUUID ordering.

I suggest reading up on time series modeling in Cassandra: http://rubyscale.com/blog/2011/03/06/basic-time-series-with-cassandra/ and http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-time-series-with-cassandra